# Python library like -Django- to easily create tables with a model class and access it

Tags: python, sql

I was wondering if anyone knows of a library that resembles the Django DB functionality to replace the standard mysql library?

So; create tables with a model class and access it like you would in a Django projects.

Django makes querying so much easier. I would honestly rather use that in my non-django projects instead of manually joining tables.

As an example, Django allows you to create two tables 'Blog' and 'Author' with a foreign key from Blog to it's Author:

```
class Author(models.Model):
            name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
            location = models.CharField(max_length=128)    

class Blog(models.Model):
            # Foreign
            author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog')

            # Columns
            title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
            content = models.CharField(max_length=6000)
            timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And, for example, access the author of a specific blog like so:

```
blog = Blog.objects.filter(id=1)
author = blog.author
```

And it gets only nicer when you have many-to-many relationships! Clean and simple.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Please make your question answerable by people who don't know Django, by explaining in details what  features you need.

Comment: Good point. Thank you. I made the adjustment in the post.